# Looping through range in worksheet and updating another range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to be able to:
Find if a cell in range `B1:B4` contains a string in range `A1:A4` then insert the string in `C1:C4`
i.e Find The first string in cell of `B1:B4` then Looks it up in `A1:A4`, If found put the string in `C1:C4` in the same row as its match in `A1:A4`
Please see my sample table and expected output.
I have started with `=INDEX(C1:C4,MATCH(1,A1:A4, B1:B4 ,0))` then thought about using VBA. See code below:

**Edit 1"**

```
Option Explicit 

Sub findMatch() 

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range
Dim cell1 As Range
Dim cell2 As Range 
Dim cell3 As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set rng1 = .Range("A1:A4")
Set rng2 = .Range("B1:B4") 
Set rng3 = .Range("C1:C4")

For Each cell1 In rng1
   For Each cell2 In rng2 
          For Each Cell3 In rng3
   If cell1 Like *'cell2'* Then 
   cell1 In rng3 = cell2 In rng3
   End If 
   Next cell2 
   Next cell1 
   Next cell3
   End With 
   
End Sub
```

**The table:**

```
`A1:A10` `B1:B10` 
+-------+--------+
+ 123   + 555    +
+-------+--------+
+ 555   + 66     +
+-------+--------+
+ S666E + 666    +
+-------+--------+
+ 77E   + 123    +
+-------+--------+
```

**Expected:**

```
`A1:A4` `B1:B4` `C1:C4`
+-------+--------+-----+
+ 123   + 555    + 123 +
+-------+--------+-----+
+ 555   + 66     + 555 +
+-------+--------+-----+
+ S666E + 666    + 666 +
+-------+--------+-----+
+ 77E   + 123    +     +
+-------+--------+-----+
```

**Edit 2**

Also tried:

```
Dim rng as Range
Set rng = Range("A:A").Find(What:=Range("B:B").Value), _ LookIn:=xlValues, _ LookAt:=xlWhole, _ SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _ SearchDirection:=xlNext, _ MatchCase:=False)
If rng Not Is Nothing Then
Range("C:C").Value =  Range("B1:B").Value 
End If
```

Comment: Can you explain exaactly the logic when returning matches? Because it's not clear

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Please see edit!

Comment: Why `666` returns `666`? Shouldn't it return `S666E`?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns since 666 is a string within S666E I would prefer it to return 666. Perhaps some kind of the use of `LIKE` keyword?

Comment: getting the values is piece of cake, you just neeed COUNTIF combined with an IF. Biggest problem is getting just the numbers from a given string. That's pure VBA

Comment: Also, `123` is present in range A1:A4, so why the expected output is nothing? shouldn't it be `77e`? As I said, the logic behind this process is not cleat at all?

Comment: `123` has been added in `C1:C4` in the first cell. B1:B4 does not contain `77` therefore 77E is not required hence null.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns it would  very usual if you could expand a bit on the use of `CountIf` and `If`

Comment: Edited OP and include a VBA approach

Comment: Your `Next`'s don't exit properly, and the `cell3` loop is redundant.

Comment: @JMP perhaps you can edit?

Answer (score 1):

This code gives your output:

```
' spreadsheet data
With Cells
.Clear
.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignRight
End With
Range("a1:a4") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose([{"123", "555", "S666E", "77E"}])
Range("b1:b4") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose([{"555",  "66", "666", "123"}])

' code
For Each cellB In Range("b1:b4")
For Each cellA In Range("a1:a4")
If InStr(cellA, cellB) > 0 Then Range("c" & cellA.Row) = cellB
Next cellA
Next cellB
```

[image: output]

If `cellB` is found in `cellA`, then `cellB` is written in column C and row of the match from column A.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have used the code part since I already have the data in a worksheet as in the first table in the OP. The code doesn't update column c is there a way of tweaking it slightly?

Comment: Remove the `With cells..End With` section - this will clear your existing data, which you don't want in your case.

Comment: @JM7 I have just done that, I have noticed that for a table of 500 rows, the Column C begins to write when a match is found but soon clears itself up. The behavior is also slow but I as long as the task is accomplished, I don't mind waiting

Comment: This is what i am using and Column C Is still not updating. I wonder why I works well for 4 rows but not for 500 rows  `Option Explicit
Sub Button2_Click()

Dim cellB As Range
Dim cellA As Range
Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = False
For Each cellB In Range("b1:b500")
For Each cellA In Range("a1:a500")
If InStr(cellA, cellB) > 0 Then Range("c" & cellA.Row) = cellB
Next cellA
Next cellB

Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = True
End Sub`

Comment: It works if you remove the `ErrorCheckingOptions` bit, and only takes about 10secs: `Option Explicit

Sub Button1_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Cells.Clear
For i = 1 To 500
Cells(i, 1) = Int(Rnd() * 20)
Cells(i, 2) = Int(Rnd() * 20)
Next i

Dim cellB As Range
Dim cellA As Range
For Each cellB In Range("b1:b500")
For Each cellA In Range("a1:a500")
If InStr(cellA, cellB) > 0 Then Range("c" & cellA.Row) = cellB
Next cellA
Next cellB
End Sub`

Comment: I assume the first for loop in your latest code for illustration. Removing the `ErrorCheckingOption` doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you can accomplish this using a formula but it will require using an additional column as a helper.

For example, paste the following formula into cell D1 (column D will be the helper column in this example). This is an array formula, so you will probably need to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to complete the formula. After this, you can copy the formula down the column. This example assumes the data goes from row 1 to 500 but you can easily change that.

```
{=IF(B1<>"", MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(B1, $A$1:$A$500)), ROW($A$1:$A$500), 0)), "")}
```

What the above formula does is look for the value of B1 in the range A1:A500 and if found then it returns the row number where it was found.

Next, paste the following formula into cell C1. Again, this is an array formula, so you will probably need to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to complete the formula. After this, you can copy the formula down the column.

```
{=IFERROR(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MAX(IF(ROW()=$D$1:$D$500, ROW($D$1:$D$500), 0)), 2)), "")}
```

What the above formula does it look for the current row number in range D1:D500 and if found it takes the row number of the row where it was found and retrieves the value found in the same row of column B.

Here is an example of what this would look like:

```
  A1:A4   B1:B4   C1:C4   D1:D4
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
+ 123   + 555   + 123   + 2     +
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
+ 555   + 66    + 555   + 3     +
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
+ S666E + 666   + 666   + 3     +
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
+ 77E   + 123   +       + 1     +
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```